# Func<void> as input parameter

Tags: c#, parameters, func

I have method in c# with some parameters:

```
public static void DeleteSingleItemInDataGrid
    (DataGrid dataGrid, String IDcolumnName, Func<int> afterCompletionMethod_ToRun)
```

I want to change third parameter type to `Func< void >` but I can't. how can I do it?

In other words *my question is how can pass a method(or function **with void result**) as a method parameter?*

Comment: use `Action` in stead

Comment: @LorentzVedeler Write that in an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A delegate referencing a method that "returns" `void` is called an `Action` in .NET lingo, and that's what the delegate type is called as well:

- [System.Action Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx)

So your method signature would be this:

```
public static void DeleteSingleItemInDataGrid
    (DataGrid dataGrid, String IDcolumnName, Action afterCompletionMethod_ToRun)
```

If you need to pass the `int` parameter to it, and not return `int`, it would be this:

```
public static void DeleteSingleItemInDataGrid
    (DataGrid dataGrid, String IDcolumnName, Action<int> afterCompletionMethod_ToRun)
```

This accepts a method taking an `int` parameter, that does not return anything (aka "returning" `void`).

This also means that you cannot create a generic method that accepts both methods returning something and methods not returning something with just one method, but need to create an overload using `Action`, and one using `Func<T>`.

Comment: I don't want to return int, I just need to return void. is there any way?

Comment: You can't "return void". A method declared as `public void Test()` must be sent via an `Action`.

Answer (score 1):

The Action delegate you can use. It will perform given task and does not return a value.